# “So fast went the bus”

Tags: inversion, style, emphasis, rhetoric

> **So fast went the bus I couldn't catch it.**

Is the structure grammatically correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct! It's other way of writing "*The bus went so fast (that) I could not catch it."*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forgive me for referencing Urban Dictionary, but that's a bit of a [yodaism](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=yodaism). (**NOT** a technical term!) Maybe you're aware of this, in which case I'd only suggest adding a comma after "bus" if you have the option. Otherwise, @MaulikV's structure would be preferable generally, but I agree, it's correct essentially.

Comment: Yoda would probably say, "So fast the bus went. Catch it I could not."

Comment: You're right; Yoda could make it even worse (yet still correct)!

Answer (score 0):

No, the sentence is not grammatically correct.

The most grammatically correct version would be:

> The bus went so fast that I couldn't catch it.

But if you insist on keeping the same structure you would have to add a comma or 'that' in the sentence, 'that' being more preferable.

> i.e. So fast went the bus that I couldn't catch it.
>
> or - So fast went the bus, I couldn't catch it. (still not grammatically correct)